# Chef: Why I cannot access the attributes defined in Role?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm using Chef 11.8.2, with open source chef server
I have the following statements in my role and cookbook file:

**roles/webserver.rb**

```
name "webserver"
description "Web Servers"
run_list %w{recipe[my_cookbook]}
default_attributes({
     "company" => "OPSCODE"
})
```

**cookbooks/my_cookbook/recipes/default.rb**

```
puts node.default.inspect
```

It only prints "{}". And I checked that the node is correctly assigned to role webserver:

```
C:\chef\chef-repo>knife node show chef-client-1
Node Name:   chef-client-1
Environment: dev
FQDN:        chef-client-1.puncha.com
IP:          192.168.1.31
Run List:    role[webserver]
Roles:       webserver
Recipes:     my_cookbook
Platform:    ubuntu 12.10
Tags:
```

Comment: have you converged the node at least once?

Comment: yes converge (run chef-client) the node at least once and add the "-l" parameter to the knife command above, in order to retrieve all the node attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to inspect the "compiled" attributes, not the default ones:

```
puts node.inspect
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I see, to use attributes in recipe, I should use the compiled properties on node object, rather than node.default.